# Capistrano でファイルのアップロードができない

Tags: capistrano

Capistrano で .env のアップロードをしたいと思っていますが、うまく動作せず困っています。（アプリは Rails で開発しています。）

アップロードのタスクは下記のように書いています。

```
desc 'Upload .env'
task :upload_dotenv do
  on roles(:app) do |host|
    upload! '.env', "#{shared_path}/.env"
  end
end
```

上記タスクの実行結果は下記の通りです。

```
$ bin/cap production deploy:upload_dotenv
DEBUG [755666a9] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2 ] as username@example.com
DEBUG [755666a9] Command: [ -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2 ]
DEBUG [755666a9] Finished in 0.292 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading .env 0.0%
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as username@example.com: scp: ~/path/to/.env: No such file or directory

scp: ~/path/to/.env: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:upload_dotenv
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Capistrano のバージョンは下記の通りです。

```
$ bin/cap -v
Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)
```

その他必要な情報などありましたら、コメントいただければ幸いです。

Comment: ~/path/to/.env: No such file or directory (~/path/to/.env が無い) 様ですが、いかがでしょう？

Comment: > ~/path/to/.env: No such file or directory (~/path/to/.env が無い) 様ですが、いかがでしょう？
`upload_dotenv` タスクで `~/path/to/.env` に `.env` をアップロードしたい（ `~/path/to/` はサーバー側のパスです）ので、アップロード前の時点でサーバー側に `.env` が無いのは問題無いかと思っています。ちなみに、 `~/path/to/.env` に空のファイルを作ってから `upload_dotenv` タスクを実行しても同様のエラーになりました。

Comment: ユーザーのホームからの相対パス `~/` になっているので、capistrano の user 設定を追記すると良いかもしれません。

または、`scp .env username@example.com:~/path/to/.env` を叩いて、scp なら正常に動作するかどうかを確認する事もできると思います。

エラーが `no such file or directory` なので、簡単な解法としては、
1. 絶対パスにする
2. upload! 前に、ディレクトリを作成する
` execute :mkdir, '-p', '~/path/to' `
等があると思います。

Comment: > ユーザーのホームからの相対パス ~/ になっているので、capistrano の user 設定を追記すると良いかもしれません。
上記は具体的にはどのような修正になりますでしょうか？

Comment: >  または、`scp .env username@example.com:~/path/to/.env` を叩いて、scp なら正常に動作するかどうかを確認する事もできると思います。
上記は正常に動作することを確認しております。（現在、capistrano とは別に上記のコマンドにて `.env` をアップロードする、といった運用を行なっています。）

Comment: >  1. 絶対パスにする
上記で想定通り動作することを確認いたしまいた！後ほど回答欄に解決の内容を書きたいと思います！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄の通りですが、パスの指定を絶対パスにすることで解決をしました。

`config/deploy.rb` に `set :deploy_to, '~/path/to'` と記述していたのですが、これをアプリケーションの絶対パス（例: `set :deploy_to, '/var/www/app_name'` ）に修正することで、 `.env` をアップロードするタスクが想定通り動作するようになりました。

@user3758624 様、素晴らしいヒントをいただきありがとうございました！